# Editor.GetEntity does not wait for user input (click)

Tags: vb.net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I have two dwg files: PID.dwg & 3D.dwg

The use case is to run a function on PID.dwg and then on 3D.dwg -- particularly in this order.

The commands used in SendCommand below are from a separate DLL file that I load using NETLOAD prior to this function's execution.

```
Dim app As AcadApplication = CType(Application.AcadApplication, AcadApplication)
' Ctype( Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.AcadApplication, 
'        Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadApplication )

If isPidAnd3dOpened() Then
    ' Activate PID document
    app.ActiveDocument = acDocPid
    'acDocPid.Activate()
    acDocPid.SendCommand("DOSOMETHINGONPID" & vbCrLf)

    ' Activate 3D document
    app.ActiveDocument = acDoc3d
    'acDoc3d.Activate()
    acDoc3d.SendCommand("DOSOMETHINGON3D" & vbCrLf)
End If
```

The function of `"DOSOMETINGON3D"` requires and input from the user using `Editor.GetEntity`.

However, when `acDoc3d.SendCommand("DOSOMETHINGON3D" & vbCrLf)` is executed, it does not pause to wait for user input.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Probably You have to wait until the command `DOSOMETHINGONPID` is finished.

In ARX it would be something like this:

```
CString activeCMDName = _T("DOSOMETHINGONPID");
bool EOL = false;
while (!EOL)
{
    CString cmds = Variable::Get(_T("CMDNAMES") );      
    if (cmds.Find( activeCMDName ) > 0 )    {
        Command::Wait();
    }
    else    {
        EOL = true;
    }
}
```

where

```
CString Variable::Get( CString name )
{
    CString OutVal;
    resbuf rb ;
    acedGetVar(name, &rb);
    OutVal.SetString(rb.resval.rstring);
    acutDelString(rb.resval.rstring);   
    return OutVal ;
}

void Command::Wait()
{
    ResBuf rb;
    rb.Add(RTSTR , _T("\\"));
    int ret = acedCmd(rb.GetFirst());
}
```

Sorry, I don't have this code in `.net`. Hope You will handle this.

Comment: I tried removing DOSOMETHINGONPID but invoked this function from the PID document and it still does not wait for user input.

Answer (score 0):

First answer is correct, `SendCommand` cannot handle asynchronous commands. [Here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/acaddocument-sendcommand-doesn-t-wait-executes-asynchronously/m-p/5475797#M43041) is a suggested solution in .Net:

```
//Create AutoCAD instance, then...

acadApp.ActiveDocument.SendCommand("(command \"NETLOAD\""+@"""C:\\acad\\networkdll\\SecondAssembly.dll"") ");
acadApp.ActiveDocument.SendCommand("#MYCOMMAND 0 ");

//Register EndCommand handler.
_DAcadApplicationEvents_EndCommandEventHandler handler = new  
    _DAcadApplicationEvents_EndCommandEventHandler(CommandEnded);

acadApp.EndCommand += handler;
waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
waitHandle.WaitOne();
acadApp.EndCommand -= handler;

//Close the startup drawing (this requires waiting @ SendCommand) because
//Drawing will cause a COMException otherwise.  'Drawing is busy'
//Mostly likely since the ActiceDocument is the startup drawing.
```

Event Handler:

```
public void CommandEnded(string globalCommandName)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(globalCommandName + " just ended.");
    waitHandle.Set();
}
```